# Add more kinds of underline colour

Tags: monaco-editor

I'm using Monaco Editor to make my own IDE. I use `provideHover` to underline certain kinds of code. It seems that different `DiagnosticCategory` or `MarkerSeverity` have impact to the colour of the underline. At the moment, it seems that there are only 4 kinds of underline colours.

```
/* Diagnostics */
enum DiagnosticCategory {
    Warning = 0,
    Error = 1,
    Suggestion = 2,
    Message = 3
}
```

Does anyone know how to add more kinds of underline colour?

Answer (score 1):

The shape and colour of the underline is determined by its CSS class, e.g. `squiggly-error`:

[image]

The constants for corresponding CSS classes are declared in [intervalTree.ts](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/d45d4ca352ea45b5c4e55e480c879237297d63e7/src/vs/editor/common/model/intervalTree.ts#L14) within VS Code project:

```
export const enum ClassName {
    EditorHintDecoration = 'squiggly-hint',
    EditorInfoDecoration = 'squiggly-info',
    EditorWarningDecoration = 'squiggly-warning',
    EditorErrorDecoration = 'squiggly-error',
    EditorUnnecessaryDecoration = 'squiggly-unnecessary',
    EditorUnnecessaryInlineDecoration = 'squiggly-inline-unnecessary',
    EditorDeprecatedInlineDecoration = 'squiggly-inline-deprecated'
}
```

The code using these constants is located in [markerDecorationsServiceImpl.ts](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/d45d4ca352ea45b5c4e55e480c879237297d63e7/src/vs/editor/common/services/markerDecorationsServiceImpl.ts#L187) (in a switch based on `MarkerSeverity`).

It doesn't seem to be designed to be extendable by configuration. Adding another underline type would probably require changes in vs core classes.